# QML Gridview with InputText

Tags: qt, model-view-controller, gridview, qml

I need a Listview with InputText on each row. Use case is a cart of items wherein qty can be changed for each row.

With the below code, Listview is rendering with a label and a text box alongside.

Issue is, all textboxes are going to have the same id, because of which, all textbox values are changing based on the last textbox value changed. Ex: If I enter 10 for the first item and 12 for the second item, even first item's qty changes to 12.

The *onEnter* is only for demonstration. It could be *onFocusChanged* going forward:

```
    ListView {
    id:list
    model: fruitModel
    x:10
    y:10
    width: parent.width-20
    height: parent.height-20
    clip:true
    anchors.fill: parent
    delegate: Row {
        width: parent.width
        height:30
        Item
        {
        property variant myData: model
        property alias value: text.text
        Text {
            id:text
            width: parent.width
            height: 30
            text:name
        }
        InputText {
            id: inp_box
            text:qty
            width:100
            height:22
            anchors.verticalCenterOffset: 15
            anchors.horizontalCenterOffset:250
            focus: true
            onEnter: {
            editQty(inp_box.text);
            }
        }
        }
    }
    focus: true
    snapMode: ListView.SnapOneItem
    ScrollBar {
        flickable: list
        vertical: true
        hideScrollBarsWhenStopped:false
    }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You should extend your `editQty` function to take the index of edited entry in `fruitModel` as an additional parameter. The index of the current entry is available within the list view's delegate as `index`. The way you did it, `editQty` has no chance to know which entry to change.